# Android - Passing args from AlertDialog to AlertDialog'host

Tags: android, dialog, parameters, main-activity

In my `MainActivity`, I generate a `DialogAlert` with 2 `EditText`s inside.
I want to recover my 2 `EditText`s in my `MainActivity` when I click on the *Positive Button* in the `DialogAlert`.

**Here my `DialogAlert` class:**

```
public class ShareDialog extends DialogFragment{

    public interface ShareDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    ShareDialogListener mListener;
    private Handler mResponseHandler;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
           mListener = (ShareDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ShareDialogListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_share, null); 
        final EditText name_place =    (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.sharePlaceName);
        final EditText description_place = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.shareDescription);
        builder.setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.shareTitle)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.share, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       String name = name_place.getText().toString();
                       String description = description_place.getText().toString();
                       mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(ShareDialog.this);

                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(ShareDialog.this);
                       ShareDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                   }
               });      
        return builder.create();
}
```

}

My `MainActivity` implements `ShareDialog.ShareDialogListener`

**In my `MainActivity` I have:**

```
    public void onClickShare(View v) {
         // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        DialogFragment dialog = new ShareDialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ShareDialog");
    }

    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Position Shared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

When I click the *Positive Button* in the `DialogAlert`, I have a `Toast` with "position shared".

I would like to recover in the method `onDialogPositiveClick()` from `MainActivity` my params **name** and **description** created in my `DialogAlert`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify the `onDialogPositiveClick` method to provide the params:

```
public interface ShareDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String name, String description);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}
```

In your alert:

```
mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(ShareDialog.this, name_place.getText(), description_place.getText());
```

And in your activity:

```
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String name, String description) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Position Shared: " + name + ", " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```